# HTML5 details and summary usability concern

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, usability

The new HTML5 details and summary elements, are currently implemented in Chrome 12.

I find one thing that is concerning me and I would like to hear your thoughts on the matter.

When the `open` attribute is set, any child nodes besides the summary element, "content" of the details element are removed from the document flow.

- I want to increase usability by
  giving the user a clear visual cue.
- So I am preventing the default
  behavior in JavaScript.
- When the summary element is toggled
  (click or keyboard), a slide down
  animation starts if the details
  element is closed or a slide up
  animation starts when the details
  element is open.

If the element is open, the open attribute is removed when the animation is finished. Otherwise, the content will be invisible immediately while the animation is still running.

**This is all fine but what about accessibility? Folks using assistive technology. They will have to wait the duration of the slide up animation before they have a confirmation that the details element is closed (because only then, the open attribute is removed)?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you set [`aria-expanded`](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-expanded) to false just before the closing animation?

Comment: That would make it even more complicated since aria-expanded and open are indicating the same state. Isn't the details element meant to replace a div with the aria-expanded attribute and no semantic meaning?

Comment: @DAD the difference being that `open` acts upon the appearance of the details element so you have to remove it after the animation. But `aria-hidden` and `aria-expanded` values (true or false) can be switched before the animation.

Comment: What I am asking myself then, is, shouldn't I use some plain div elements in combination with the aria-expanded attribute and CSS visibility? It looks like the details element is very limited in its usage. For example, to accomplish the slide down effect on a closed details element, I need to open it with JavaScript, grap its height and then bring it back to the initial state, just because the contents of a closed details element are completely removed instead of hidden.

Comment: @DAD I think you should ask this as another question because I don't have a definitive answer. The major problem is that it won't work if javascript is disabled so Id recommend using details/summary and if it's not supported fall back to the polyfill.

Comment: @Knu Isn't that what we aim for? Separation of content, style and behavior. The content can still be accessible with JavaScript disabled. Thanks for your help though, it's appreciated.

Comment: @DAD When details/summary is supported natively, the interactivity is working whether JS is off or not that's why I wouldn't use "plain div elements" directly.

Answer (score 0):

Make your pages functional without any script at all, that will help usability a lot. Only add script where it enhances usability - things that slide up/down or fade in/out may look cool the first time, but after making users wait several times for effects to do their thing before they can access the content being revealed, it quickly becomes tiresome.

Comment: While I understand your standpoint I am not completely sure if it is applicable in this case since the slide up and down effects have a duration of merely 250ms and they are used everywhere, e.g. the Wordpress admin.

Comment: Is "everyone does it" the only endorsement you can cite? No usability studies? Or user comprehension or legibility? Nothing?